# How do I check if a function that returns FVec2 type value equals another FVec2?

Tags: c++

I have a function that returns a value of type FVec2. I want to compare the value that this function returns with an FVec2 so that I see if they are equal (in an if statement), and then perform an operation when they are equal. I am using "==" operator, but I get an error that says: "no operator "==" matches these operands". How should I compare FVec2 values?

```
if (structure.function() == FVec2{ -94.f, -50.f }) {

    //code
}
```

Comment: We have no idea what a `FVec2` type is.  Please include a [mcve] in the question.

Comment: So define an `operator <=>` for it.

Comment: @RichardCritten I am sorry, I should have done so.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow That is precisely what I did a couple of minutes ago. I am C++ beginner so excuse me for such a dumb question.